# How to update user data in horizon?

Tags: rethinkdb, horizon

I have a horizon app and try to update user data, have no errors but when I look in admin, the table is not changed. I probably miss something stupid. What I do is:

```
var user = this.props.data.horizon.currentUser();
user.data = {};
user.data.email = this.refs.email.value;
user.data.phone = this.refs.phone.value;
this.props.data.horizon("users").replace(user);
```

any ideas what am I doing wrong?